# Is the use of Nested Cross Validation and train- test CV necessary or an overkill?

Tags: r, cross-validation, caret, training-error

I have been relatively obsessed lately in the proper way of selecting a model (including tuning hyper parameters) and then assessing model performance.

I have read various posts and the approach I have found to be optimal (by combining information from different sources) is the following:

1. Randomly split the full dataset into train (80%) and test (20%)
2. Do not consider the test step until you reach step 5
3. Use (nested) 10-fold cross validation within the train set for model selection and hyper parameter tuning (I think the caret package in r does that very well as it allows you to do pre processing such as scaling or imputation in each fold). In other words in each fold I split the train set into train and validation set
4. Select the best model (best in terms of number of nodes, cost-complexity trade off etc) from the nested CV and run it on the complete train data set
5. Apply that best model in the test set and get the model performance metric you are interested (that can act as a fully unbiased model assessment as the test set was not used at all since that step). For example if I was building a decision tree I would get the accuracy for that best model on the complete train set and on the test set and examine the difference.

Now my question is, if these processing steps are indeed sufficient or not. Am I missing an essential step or should I further split any steps?

One addition in particular that I was thinking is to do cross validation on the initial full dataset by using that best model and then examine if the average CV difference between train and test set accuracy stayed (bordeline) the same with the difference from step 5. I guess one of the reasons for considering this is to ensure that the selection of test set in step 1 was well curated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The above procedure addresses the part of computing an unbiased performance estimate. In order to also get a final model you can run a simple cross-validation on the full dataset, pick the best hyperparameters based on the cross-validated performance, and train a final model with the best hyperparameters on the full dataset.

Comment: @ George I am not sure I agree. I find it much more robust to use the validation data (through the nested CV) to fine-tune the model hyper parameters. Hence the model occasionally sees the validation dataset, but never does it “learn” from it. Since this procedure can itself lead to some over fitting to the validation set, the performance of the selected model should be confirmed by measuring its performance on the Test set. So I would favour that approach over your sugggestion. My question was whether I sould also do a follow up CV on the full dataset using that best model.

Comment: You can have a look at this work https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10994-018-5714-4 for a more detailed explanation of my comment. Refer to algorithm 3 in section 2.2, and particularly the explanation right before algorithm 3. You can also have a look at the empirical evaluation, which demonstrates that the performance of the returned model using the procedure I described matches  (or even exceeds) the performance estimate returned by nested CV. You might also be interested in one of the alternative methods which are more computationally efficient (TT or the introduced one).